# How to solve the error: Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again. (Gmail Add-on)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a Gmail Add-on deployed on marketplace, it was working fine but now when a user have multiple accounts logged into gmail and tries to install my add-on. It shows the error

`Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.`

`Please check the address and try again.`

[image: Error image]

The URL of opened popup is (script_id is my project's script id ): `https://script.google.com/macros/u/1/s/<script_id>/authorize?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.addons.current.action.compose%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.addons.current.message.metadata%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.addons.execute%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fscript.external_request%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile`
When only one account is logged into Gmail, then it works as expected and add-on is installed normally.

I checked other solutions to the same problem, then say we need to remove `/u/1/` from the URL. I copy pasted the URL into another tab and removed `/u/1/` from the URL. I still got the same error. Also, this URL is generated by Google and not by us, so we cannot edit it.

Any help for the problem mentioned above will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well known issue regarding Apps Script and the way Google handles multiple accounts being logged in.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#fix_issues_with_multiple_google_accounts) states the following regarding this matter:

> If you're logged into multiple Google Accounts at the same time, you might have trouble accessing your Apps Script projects, add-ons, and web apps. Multi-login, or being logged into multiple Google Accounts at once, **isn't supported for Apps Script, add-ons, or web apps**.

Possible workarounds for this include:

- Logging  out of all your Google Accounts and only log in to the one that has the Apps Script project, add-on, or web app you need to access.
- Opening an incognito window in Google Chrome, or an equivalent private browsing window, and log in to the Google Account that has the Apps Script project, add-on, or web app you need to access.

This is currently being tracked on this report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374); I suggest you star it as any updates regarding this will be posted there.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Script Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#fix_issues_with_multiple_google_accounts).