# error in create script (google apps script) that return html from file that store in the drive

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

i need to do a script that return html file that store on google drive (one script create the file ans the 2'nd return it), this is the script:

```
function doGet(e)
{
// return the right file According to his name
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(DriveApp.getFolderById(the-id-of-the-folder).getFilesByName( e.parameter['p']).next().getBlob(););
}

function createPage() {

// read the template html from file
  var message = DocumentApp.openById(the-id-of-the-file-that-contant-the-html-template).getBody().getText();

//message.replace - put the address of the deployment with the parameter in herf tag
  message=message.replace('{url2}','the-deployment-address?p=123.html');

// create the html file for the deployment can return it
  DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name-of-the-folder).next().createFile('123.html',message);
}
```

i think that is a Permissions problem, beacuse if i open by myself (i mean press on the link) the page open and if i open it from someone else it's say error.
the problem is that the script have all Permissions to work like me, and no matter who do that.

[image]

Comment: - [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to have a better understanding on your issue?

Comment: this is the code...

Comment: try ths https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw1QEOOEBPt40EoX5PBoCVyoTQpJcCW3j3tqB2E9lv8fOZF_mm7tzJfRq6b6hPq7P-eOw/exec?i=123

Comment: [Edit] to show ``Execute as:`` and `Who has access:`

Comment: Btw, I can access your script just fine.

Comment: show Execute as: and Who has access:  what is mean?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions - ``Who has access``

Comment: i did it  Who has access: anyone Execute as: like me

Comment: from incoginto it's work and from my accounts (I tried at least 3 different ones) no work... By the way, what is the right way to do it, because I don't think Google Script and drive is the right way...

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71568447/how-to-solve-the-error-sorry-unable-to-open-the-file-at-this-time-please-chec  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780096/google-web-app-wont-run-when-logged-into-multiple-google-accounts

Comment: thank you.         what the right way to do something like that?

Comment: Log out of all accounts and login into only one account.

Comment: thanks, I meant this mini server, is there a correct/different way to implement it?

Comment: If the only thing that changes is the `url2`, I think a Html Template in the script editor would be better.